# series convergence of $(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n})^{2a}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> The series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty
>  \bigg(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^{2a}$$ converges if
>
> $(a)$ $a>\frac{1}{3}$.
>
> $(b)$ $a<\frac{1}{3}$.
>
> $(c)$ $a<\frac{1}{2}$.
>
> $(d)$ $a>\frac{1}{6}$.

Since that $2a$ appears to the power of $\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n}$, I went for the logarithmic test at first attempt. Taking $u_n=(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n})^{2a}$, we have $$\lim n\log\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}}\\=2a \lim n\log\frac{\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n+1}-\sin\frac{1}{n+1}}\\=2a\lim \frac{\log(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}-2a\lim \frac{\log(\frac{1}{n+1}-\sin \frac{1}{n+1})}{\frac{1}{n}}$$ 
Now the two limits on RHS are in $\frac{\infty}{0}$ form, so L'Hopital is not of any use here. I couldn't find a way to evaluate the limits by some other methods also. Is log test applicable for this type of tests, or any other method would be suitable here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Comparison test, use $x - \sin x ~ x^3/6 [x \to 0^+]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {x-\sin x} {x^{3}}=\frac  1 6$ as seen by applying L'Hopital's Rule twice. Hence the given series converges iff $\sum \frac 1 {n^{6a}}$ converges which is true iff $a >\frac 1 6$.